# How to download the uploaded file in java?

Tags: java

I need to put the preview of my uploaded file and in that preview I need to put download button after clicking that it should download

This is my html for uploading the file: And my server side code for uploading file:

```
<form action="FileUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"></input>
<input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

```
public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            ServletFileUpload sf = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
            List < FileItem > files = sf.parseRequest(request);
            for (FileItem item: files) {
                item.write(new File("Location where to upload the file" + item.getName()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: I don't see a specific question here. What have you tried? What is going wrong?

Comment: I have done uploading part. I need help in previewing the uploaded file and in that preview I need to place download button to download my uploaded file.

Comment: Why does it matter whether the file is uploaded before preview or not? It is a simple file on your server file system. What is your specific problem here? Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes...It is on my file system..For learning purpose, I am just trying to download the uploaded file.

Comment: @Maali, If you want help could you please ask a specific question. What is here is way too vague for anybody to answer. If you are just looking for a general approach to solving a problem then there are any amount of on-line tutorials that might help you.